# what would happen if I installed a Ubuntu with md5 hashes that are different fom the intended ones

Tags: system-installation

What would happen if I installed Ubuntu with md5 hashes that do not match the intended ones.

Comment: It would be a bad install and some/all features wouldn't work. If you are lucky it might be a small bug. If you're unlucky, it might not work at all, and completely freeze your computer.

Answer (score 2):

Anything could happen. You could find that you are installing Windows! :D Or that your setup is compromised in some way, with keyloggers and botnets and whatnot. Or it simply wouldn't install, because the affected file is crucial to installation.